# Populating large HTML div in JavaScript, based on JSON response from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, .net, razor

I currently have a significant amount of HTML inside a div which is generated within an iteration from a GET request to my .net core server.

Some of the values in the HTML is dynamic data returned from the server.

I've added a button to my website, which when pressed, makes an AJAX call to the server to return a JSON object representing the dynamic values for the next iteration.

So, I would like the JavaScript to add a new div to the DOM, which is the same, and has my dynamic values populated based on the JSON response.

For context, the DIV looks like this (which is from a bootstrap template I purchased):

```
   <div class="card">
        <!-- Card header START -->
        <div class="card-header border-0 pb-0">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <!-- Avatar -->
                    <div class="avatar me-2">
                        <a href="#!"> <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="@post.ProfileImageUrl" alt="profile picture"> </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Info -->
                    <div>
                        <div class="nav nav-divider">
                            <h6 class="nav-item card-title mb-0"> <a href="#!"> @post.ProfileName </a></h6>
                            <span class="nav-item small"> @post.PostTime</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Card feed action dropdown START -->
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="text-secondary btn btn-secondary-soft-hover py-1 px-2" id="cardFeedAction" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- Card feed action dropdown menu -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardFeedAction">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-bookmark fa-fw pe-2"></i>Save post</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person-x fa-fw pe-2"></i>Unfollow lori ferguson </a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-x-circle fa-fw pe-2"></i>Hide post</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-slash-circle fa-fw pe-2"></i>Block</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-flag fa-fw pe-2"></i>Report post</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Card feed action dropdown END -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Card header END -->
        <!-- Card body START -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <p><strong>@post.PostBody</strong></p>
            <!-- Card img -->
            <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="@post.PostImageUrl" alt="Post">
            <!-- Feed react START -->
            <ul class="nav nav-stack py-3 small">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#!"> <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill pe-1"></i>Liked (56)</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#!"> <i class="bi bi-chat-fill pe-1"></i>Comments (12)</a>
                </li>
                <!-- Card share action START -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ms-sm-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link mb-0" href="#" id="cardShareAction" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="bi bi-reply-fill flip-horizontal ps-1"></i>Share (3)
                    </a>
                    <!-- Card share action dropdown menu -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardShareAction">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-envelope fa-fw pe-2"></i>Send via Direct Message</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-bookmark-check fa-fw pe-2"></i>Bookmark </a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-link fa-fw pe-2"></i>Copy link to post</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-share fa-fw pe-2"></i>Share post via …</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-pencil-square fa-fw pe-2"></i>Share to News Feed</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- Card share action END -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Card body END -->
        <!-- Card footer START -->
        <div class="card-footer border-0 pt-0">
            <!-- Load more comments -->
            <a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-link-loader btn-sm text-secondary d-flex align-items-center" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true">
                <div class="spinner-dots me-2">
                    <span class="spinner-dot"></span>
                    <span class="spinner-dot"></span>
                    <span class="spinner-dot"></span>
                </div>
                Load more comments
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Card footer END -->
    </div>
    <!-- Card feed item END -->
```

Question:

There's a lot of HTML here. What's the best way to build this out in Javascript? Is it just a case of biting the bullet and writing all of the JS code to create each element/class?

Would this be the best practice? Because it effectively means I'm maintaining the HTML markup in two places..

Thank you..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually save the html of the template to be rendered inside an hidden element. Then I can always access it using that `element.innerHTML`. You could use specialized `script` tag instead. But the `innerHTML` part is the same.

After having the HTML as string you have 2 options

1. build the string with the values you want to populate, then add that as `innerHTML` to the target container.
2. but a better approach is to create an element from that `html` (see function below) then append it and manipulate it otherwise.

```js
// render 5 cards 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  var html = document.querySelector("#card-template").innerHTML;
  var elem = elemFromString(html)

  // change something
  elem.querySelector(".card-body>p strong").innerText = "card " + i

  // append
  document.querySelector("#container").append(elem)
}


// usefull utility 
function elemFromString(html) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("div");
  dummy.innerHTML = html.trim();
  if (dummy.children.length > 1) {
    console.error("expecting one wrapping element for html. will return only firstChild")
  }
  var result = dummy.firstChild;
  result.parentNode.removeChild(result)
  return result;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container">
</div>


<div id="card-template" style="display:none">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- Card header START -->
    <div class="card-header border-0 pb-0">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <!-- Avatar -->
          <div class="avatar me-2">
            <a href="#!"> <img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="@post.ProfileImageUrl" alt="profile picture"> </a>
          </div>
          <!-- Info -->
          <div>
            <div class="nav nav-divider">
              <h6 class="nav-item card-title mb-0"> <a href="#!"> @post.ProfileName </a></h6>
              <span class="nav-item small"> @post.PostTime</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Card feed action dropdown START -->
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="text-secondary btn btn-secondary-soft-hover py-1 px-2" id="cardFeedAction" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
          </a>
          <!-- Card feed action dropdown menu -->
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardFeedAction">
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-bookmark fa-fw pe-2"></i>Save post</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person-x fa-fw pe-2"></i>Unfollow lori ferguson </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-x-circle fa-fw pe-2"></i>Hide post</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-slash-circle fa-fw pe-2"></i>Block</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-flag fa-fw pe-2"></i>Report post</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Card feed action dropdown END -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Card header END -->
    <!-- Card body START -->
    <div class="card-body">
      <p><strong>@post.PostBody</strong></p>
      <!-- Card img -->
      <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="@post.PostImageUrl" alt="Post">
      <!-- Feed react START -->
      <ul class="nav nav-stack py-3 small">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#!"> <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill pe-1"></i>Liked (56)</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#!"> <i class="bi bi-chat-fill pe-1"></i>Comments (12)</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Card share action START -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown ms-sm-auto">
          <a class="nav-link mb-0" href="#" id="cardShareAction" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="bi bi-reply-fill flip-horizontal ps-1"></i>Share (3)
          </a>
          <!-- Card share action dropdown menu -->
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="cardShareAction">
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-envelope fa-fw pe-2"></i>Send via Direct Message</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-bookmark-check fa-fw pe-2"></i>Bookmark </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-link fa-fw pe-2"></i>Copy link to post</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-share fa-fw pe-2"></i>Share post via …</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i class="bi bi-pencil-square fa-fw pe-2"></i>Share to News Feed</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Card share action END -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Card body END -->
    <!-- Card footer START -->
    <div class="card-footer border-0 pt-0">
      <!-- Load more comments -->
      <a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-link-loader btn-sm text-secondary d-flex align-items-center" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true">
        <div class="spinner-dots me-2">
          <span class="spinner-dot"></span>
          <span class="spinner-dot"></span>
          <span class="spinner-dot"></span>
        </div>
        Load more comments
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Card footer END -->
  </div>
  <!-- Card feed item END -->
</div>
```